# WPF CommandParameter is NULL when binding to element

Tags: wpf, commandparameter

I am trying to bind the textbox text to Commandparameter. However in the call to CanExecute the parameter passed is null. Changing the text also does not call CanExecute.

Is my use case valid ?

View

```
<Window x:Class="PlayButtonCommandParameter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:playButtonCommandParameter="clr-namespace:PlayButtonCommandParameter"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <playButtonCommandParameter:TestViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
  </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
      <TextBox Name="Test">Hello</TextBox>
      <Button Content="Element Name Click" 
              Command="{Binding TestCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=Text}"></Button>
      <Button Content="RelativeSource Click" 
              Command="{Binding RelativeSourceCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, 
                                  Path=Children[0].Text}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ICommand testCommand = new TestCommand();

    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get { return testCommand; }
    }

    private readonly ICommand relativeSourceCommand = new TestCommand();

    public ICommand RelativeSourceCommand
    {
        get { return relativeSourceCommand; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Command

```
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var text = parameter as string;

        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Comment: mmh, the first button works. But the second with relative source binding won´t work. Whats interesting is that the PropertyWindow in Visual Studio displays the correct value for the CommandParameter-Binding. But on runtime null is passed to CanExecute

Answer (score 2):

No your expectations are not valid. First:

> Changing the text also does not call CanExecute

no one is going to call your `CanExecute` handler unless you fire the `CanExecuteChanged` event in your ICommand. In your case you will have to handle yourself the `TextBox` `TextChanged` event and raise the `CanExecuteChanged` from within your `ICommand` implementation.

For this simple case i would suggest you to use a instance of a `RoutedCommand` instead. There is a CommandManager that listens for changes in the UI and will raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event for you.

Just follow this simple steps [How to: Create a RoutedCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)